# Can neuroevolution be combined with gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithms, gradient-descent, neat, neuroevolution

Is there any precedent for using a neuroevolution algorithm, like NEAT, as a way of getting to an initialization of weights for a network that can then be fine-tuned with gradient descent and back-propagation?

I wonder if this may be a faster way of getting to a global minimum before starting a decent to a local using backpropagation with a large set of input parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper [The Comparison and Combination of Genetic and Gradient Descent Learning in Recurrent Neural Networks: An Application to Speech Phoneme Classification](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5071/d5f447a99f7e4d522f07f7752ca1435e13c9.pdf) (2007), by Rohitash Chandra and Christian W. Omlin, uses genetic algorithms to train a recurrent neural network and then uses gradient descent to fine tune the trained model.

The paper [Evolutionary Stochastic Gradient Descent for Optimization of Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.06773.pdf) (2018), by Xiaodong Cui, Wei Zhang, Zoltán Tüske and Michael Picheny, also combines evolutionary algorithms and gradient descent, but, in this case, they alternate between a gradient descent step and an evolution step. This is an example of a *evolutionary stochastic gradient descent* (ESGD) method, as opposed to a [population-based training (PBT)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09846.pdf) method, which uses only evolutionary algorithms to train neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be in addition to the papers that nbro linked to above uber's ai research team has a very interesting combination of sgd and neuroevolution which they have dubbed "safe mutations". In the algorithm each genome undergoes a bit of sgd to improve its fitness before the speciation, elitism, and reproduction processes. I imagine this has an effect of searching for genomes which are well suited for sgd optimization, and in my opinion does really provide the best of both a worlds. Here is the link to the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06563 . What I think would be a cool for this combination of the two would be its use in conjunction with the es-hyperneat/hyperneat neuroevolution algorithms in which a small genome cppn encodes large phenotype rnns using the rnns substrate (its structure represented with cartesian coordinates) as the cppns input. If a small amount sgd is used on the rnn's to improve fitness then what you end up with is a cppn is being evolved to encode very general rnn networks that can then be optimized to specific domains via sgd. I like this because then your neuroevolution doesnt occur on a massive rnn and you can create cppns that recognize the general problem you wish to solve if your clever with your fitness evaluation.